# dde excel 2010 links don't all work

Tags: excel, vba, windows-7, virtual-machine, dde

I have a program installed on my pc (windows 7 server virtual machine)
which exports data to dde excel. 
The export is very buggy, as parts of the dde link does not work part of the time and so on.

I've seen a [possible solution](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excel/thread/7c8f845d-c4aa-4627-9008-3251d2772536/) that suggests that maybe the dde links should be closed before each run here

```
Application.DDETerminateAll
```

or

```
 For i = 1 To 1000
        Application.DDETerminate (i) ' Closes all DDE links whose channels might be open
    Next i
```

I am looking for the solution and thought that maybe the dde settings 
can be modified to fix this via excel 2010 or windows registery settings.

Comment: Hi devmonster, for clarification purposes: Have you tested the vba solution above and need a fix, or are you looking for a vba program that accomplishes the vba process noted by the article?

Comment: need a fix. as I said, half the dde links work and other half do not.

Answer (score 2):

DDE has long since been deprecated.

On Google you will find many questions about DDE not working on Windows 7.
Suggested solutions have included:

- Disabling UAC.
- Registering DDE messages in the message filter of the receiving program

  ```
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_DDE_FIRST, MSGFLT_ADD);
  ...
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_DDE_LAST, MSGFLT_ADD);
  ```
- Elevating the sending program's permissions.

See if any of that works for you.

Comment: Hi GSerg, thanks for the reply. 1. UAC is allready set to 'never notify'. 2. I don't understand what you are saying and how does it help. 3. I am allready running that program as an administrator.

Comment: DDE does work up to and including Windows 10. ÖEnd users have to allow Excel to accept DDE though. And DDE still has a place for high-volume real-time data, it's a faster communications channel than COM.

Comment: @toolforger I didn't say it has been removed, I said [it's deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070226-00/?p=27863).

Comment: Sure, but just saying it's "deprecated" doesn't help the reader determine under what circumstances there are reasons to use it anyway.